# Playing a looping soundtrack

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am making a game and I want to have a list of songs play in the background and loop once it's gone though them all.  To do this I loop through creating `MediaPlayer`s and calling `setNextMediaPlayer` with next player in the list unless it's the last item; then I set it back to the first item in the list.  This works but when it loops and tries to play the first song again it tells me that I called `play()` in an invalid state.  So I added an `OnCompleteListener` so when a song ends I call `prepare()` on it again but that didn't help.  What do I need to do to a `MediaPlayer` that has reached the end in order to get it to play again?

-= UPDATE =-
Here's my code for initializing the `MediaPlayers` (minus the try's and catches since that just clutters it up):

```
String[] assets = manager.list("songs");
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(assets));

for(String name : assets)
{
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = manager.openFd("songs/"+name);

    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    player.setOnCompletionListener(_reset);
    player.prepare();

    if(_songs.size() > 0)
    {
        _songs.get(_songs.size() - 1).setNextMediaPlayer(player);
    }

    _songs.add(player);
}

_songs.get(_songs.size() - 1).setNextMediaPlayer(_songs.get(0));
```

Comment: `setNextMediaPlayer` is only available in `API 16`+ are you OK with that?
When do you call `prepare()` in the first case i.e. without overriding `OnComleteListener`?

Comment: Yup, I am ok with that.  I updated my question to contain the code I use to init the `MediaPlayers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the same error after calling `prepare` inside `onCompleteListener` it might be because the next `MediaPlayer`, which is now not prepared, is invoked before `onCompleteListener`.

I would suggest a different approach that might solve your problem and be more efficient as well:

- Maintain the order of songs in some data structure such as `Circular Linked List` so you give it the current song name and it give you the next one
- Prepare and start playing the first song
- Override `onPrepared` and get the next song name from your data structure then call `setNextMediaPlayer` with a newly created and prepared `MediaPlayer` object

I believe this approach is more efficient because you do not create many instances of `MediaPlayer` in advance. Also, you provide a prepared `nextMediaPlayer` every time when you start the current song.

Comment: I went a slightly different route but this put me on the right path!  Thank you!